# How to fill a line in 2D image along a given radius with the data in a given line image?

Tags: dm-script

I want to fill a 2D image along its polar radius, the data are stored in a image where each row or column corresponds to the radius in target image. How can I fill the target image efficiently? Such as with iradius or some functions? I do not prefer a pix-pix operation.

Comment: Could you post a before / after transformation image to clarify what you're looking for? If I understand you right, you want a rect->polar transform, but this will always include some sort of interpolation. So most likely you will want to use the `warp` command.

Comment: Yes, I need a rect->polar tranform. An image stores the data, each raw is the line corresponding a given theta, from 0 to 360. The interpolation is also needed, but I want to know a fast tranform method first. :) Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If line# corresponds to a certain radius, are line-lenghts increasing (as r gets bigger) in your data? My answer below uses a single value per radius, but the same code could be expanded to have 2D images. Is this all you need, or do you have further questions. A interpolation is *always* required for the transform unless you have different line-lengths for different radii and the #data points match exactly with the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```c
number maxR = 100
image rValues := realimage("I(r)",4,maxR)
rValues = 10 + trunc(100*random())
image plot :=realimage("Ring",4,2*maxR,2*maxR)
rValues.ShowImage()
plot.ShowImage()
plot = rValues.warp(iradius,0)
```

You might also want to check out the relevant example code from the F1 help documentation of GMS itself:
[image]

---

Explaining `warp` a bit:

```c
plot = rValues.warp(iradius,0)
```

Assigns values to `plot` based on a value-lookup in `rValues`.
For each pixel in `plot` a coordinate position in `rValues` is computed, and the value is simply looked up. If the computed coordinate is non-integer, bilinear interpolation between the 4 closest points is used.

In the example, the two 'formulas' for the coordinate calculation are simple `x' = iradius` and `y' = 0` where `iradius` is an expression computed from the coordinate in `plot`, for convenience.

You can feed any expression into the parameters for `warp( )` and the command is closely related to just using the square bracket notation of addressing values. In fact, the only difference is that `warp` performs the bilinear interpolation of values instead of truncating the coordinates to integer values.

Comment: That's OK. I understand your code. Thank you very much!!